# Where did my participation tags go?

Tags: support, tags, participation

I posted my [first question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260736/what-happens-to-questions-whose-tags-are-burned-down) on [Meta Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/575171/divi) yesterday and got some upvotes. But even today, it displays 0 tags with:

> You have not participated in any tags

Where did my tags go?

[image]

Comment: Questions do not count towards the tag score - answers do.

Comment: @juergen d: But the definition of a tag is: "A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question." So, in addition to answers, why don't questions matter?

Comment: On second thought - I think it should display the tag with score zero. But the tag calculation script runs only once a day. Your question was 19 hours ago. Maybe you just need to wait a little longer.

Comment: @juergend Yeah, I'd say it's probably because they haven't been updated yet. I've got a few tags myself where I only have questions but not answers, and they display a 0; I'd assume it'd also display the 0 here too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the tag-related scripts run daily at 03:00 UTC (about 3 hours from now), so you'll have to wait until then for that section to update. All of the tags that appear there will have a zero next to them since questions do not count towards the tag score, but you can hover over each of those numbers to see the number of questions you've asked under each of them as well as your overall question score.