# Did something change with the review queue system and badges?

Tags: support, review, badges

Over on Science Fiction & Fantasy, I've just been re-awarded a [Steward badge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/101/steward?userid=33591) that I had earned almost a year ago. When I visit the badge page, I see that they say they're awarded for different things:

> Awarded 4 mins ago  for reviewing Low Quality Posts
> Awarded May 14 '20 at 5:18  for 1000 reviews, over 200 actioned in the old review system

What does "in the old review system" mean? What's changed in the review system, and why was I (and everyone else) awarded the badge *again*?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360194/steward-badges-being-re-awarded-suddenly

Comment: You've been awarded it twice.

Comment: @Catija - I only meet the criteria for one queue, though, and it's only supposed to be awarded once per queue...

Comment: Also I get my steward badges again. All of them.

Comment: ... so... we're changing it so that it can be awarded multiple times - once for every 1k reviews... but I wasn't expecting that to go live network wide... now.

Comment: @Catija The idea is very good! But note: do something with the robo-closures. Nearly all of the most profilic reviewers, particularly the ones active on many sites, close-reject-delete practically everything what they can. Expect the solution of the SO VtC problem, but expect also an unbelievable amount of whining about unfairly closed posts and rejected edits. Well, and forget also this welcomingness idea.

Comment: \o/ 50 gold badges for me! Robo reviewing finally pays out!

Comment: @Catija so now changes are announced in a comment? Well, better than nothing. Thanks!

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating - animuson mentioned on the other post that a post should be rolling out and this change wasn't supposed to be rolling out quite yet...

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating ... Um... As I said, it wasn't supposed to come out now. There's a post coming later this afternoon that outlines the entire change.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating be happy, we go from 6 to 8 weeks to -6 to 8 minutes ...

Comment: @rene LOL!! Good one! Well, still, such a big change right before weekend... not something I'd do myself.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Thursday is a pretty normal day for us to ship stuff. Still gives us Friday to work on stuff.

Comment: @Catija but only Friday, why not ship when you have more days to fix the bugs and improve stuff?

Comment: @Catija This isn't an award of new badges for ⩾2k reviews, it's just a re-award of the existing badges. I [got an extra copy of all my existing Stewards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otxwB.png), but I have 3k close reviews and 1.3k Suggested Edits reviews.

Comment: Possible dupe to the official announcement (buggy network-wide, but expected in the future): [Visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/241919)