# Steward badge can now be awarded multiple times -- backfill details

Tags: discussion, review, badges, announcements, review-badges

As we announced in our post on [visual design changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues/) to the Review Queues, the Steward badge can now be earned more than once per queue.

The purpose of this post is not to debate the merits of this decision ([another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360270/gold-badge-parity-and-balance-award-criteria-of-the-steward-badge-changes) already exists), but to explain the nuts and bolts of how it will be backfilled.

This is how it will appear on your profile if you have earned it multiple times:

[image]

Once we push the visual design changes live across the network, this is how badge attainment will look on /review/close/stats:

[image]

For those of you who have already completed enough reviews to earn multiple Steward badges, we will be retroactively awarding them to you, starting today. The backfill script will run about twice an hour, and your achievements trophy will light up as each one is awarded. For those of you who have done thousands and thousands of reviews, things may be a bit noisy, so we thank you in advance for your patience. It may take up to two days for all of your badges to show up.

Comment: There is a question about if additional badges should be awarded using a different criteria: [Gold badge parity and balance - award criteria of the steward badge changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360270/282094)

Comment: Shouldn't the wording be updated then? It's currently "Complete at least 1,000 review tasks. This badge is awarded once per review type. This badge can be awarded multiple times."

Comment: I'll be patient when it rolls on Stack Overflow. Very patient, I promise ... ;)

Comment: @BenjaminW. Looks like it was updated. On Stack Overflow I see "Complete at least 1,000 review tasks. This badge is awarded multiple times per review type. This badge can be awarded multiple times." Although that last sentence seems redundant now. Isn't it?

Comment: Ooh, think we could do this for the Marshal badge as well - another badge for every additional 500 flags?  It'd be excellent for us Charcoal users ;)

Comment: About the only Stack Exchange question that contains "thank you in advance" where it probably shouldn't be edited out... :-)

Comment: @BenjaminW. The copy was memory cached so didn't change until the next build went out.

Comment: Will this be considered for the Marshal badge as well?

Comment: Genie out of the bottle: [Allow us to earn the Marshal badge multiple times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360338/282094) - price of gold hits all-time low.