# Steward badge description rephrasing

Tags: feature-request, bug, badges, wording

[Now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360279/339911) when you can earn Steward badge multiple times inside a single review queue the [following phrase](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/185/steward) looks weird:

> Complete at least 1,000 review tasks. This badge is awarded multiple times per review type. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

I suggest removing the last sentence since it's obvious that badge can be awarded multiple times if you can earn it multiple times inside a single queue.

Actually even before the recent changes were done existence of several queues assumed that badges can be awarded more than once.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360204/135565 related.