# Old question title for (cross-site) links

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, title

I have [an answer](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11340/176217) on ruSO.meta. That answer contains a link to the MSE question [Steward badge description rephrasing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360294/339911). When I added the link to MSE question the question's title had a typo, in particular "rephasing" (no "r" letter). After that I fixed the typo on MSE, but the question's title from link on ruSO.meta remains old:

> [image: link on ruSO.meta post]

Maybe I just have to blame caching but still... looks like a bug. Almost 2 days have passed.

Comment: As per the original announcement of this feature, [Replace trilogy raw links with the current question title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title): *It will always insert the current title into the post, at post creation time. However, should the title subsequently change it will not be updated unless the post is edited.*

Comment: @Sonic heh I made a typo in a "typo" word :)

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog btw the post preview on ruSO.meta contains current title, so there is inconsistency with preview/result.

Comment: That's because the preview is rendered live, rather than using prior cached HTML from the previous edit.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog yep. The reason is obvious but according to WYSIWYG rule this is a bug.