# Allow us to earn the Marshal badge multiple times

Tags: feature-request, flagging-badges

The logic of these two badges, Steward and Marshal, are similar:

1. Complete at least 1,000 review tasks. This badge is awarded multiple times per review type (Steward).
2. Raise 500 helpful flags (Marshal).

But Steward can be awarded for every additional 1000 reviews, whereas Marshal cannot be awarded multiple times.  I propose that be changed:  Allow us to earn Marshal for every additional 500 helpful flags.

Marshal is a badge that rewards an activity that is actually helpful to the site - helpful flagging.  It's relatively hard to earn and can't be earned like Citizen Patrol - they have to be helpful, and it'd be especially nice for those of us who participate in Charcoal ;)
Thoughts?

Comment: Woah. That would be 49 more gold badges for me on SO. I think that's way too much!

Comment: @honk Everything is multiplied by eleventy billion on Stack Overflow.  Maybe every additional 1000 flags, then ;)

Comment: That would still mean > +130 flags for some people as there are people with > 130,000 helpful flags on Stack Overfow.

Comment: There are people around 80-100k reviews on SO in a single queue. Someone got 195 Steward badges with the recent roll out. We have a Scrooge McDuck situation already with all these golds. :D

Comment: How bout Prestige mode? After earning the first one for 500 flags, the next takes 600, then 750, then 1000, then....?

Comment: @CanadianLuke then it'd be too easy to get, especially for SO and Charcoal users.  I'd also like it to be consistent with the Steward badge.

Comment: @Ollie I don’t see how increasing the threshold for the next badge makes it too easy to get. Is it 500 flags _in total_ for the first badge, then 600 flags _in total_ for the next badge, or is it 500 flags for the first badge, then 600 _additional_ flags for the next badge?

Comment: @CanadianLuke Prestige mode sounds like a good idea, although maybe they should rise by 100 each time:  first: 500, second requires 600 *additional* flags, third 700 etc.

Comment: This looks like a stellar way to incentivise people on smaller stacks to keep the comment section clean and tidy.

Comment: I see the points y'all have made about too many badges on SO.  I've spent more time in SOBotics and Charcoal lately and have accumulated quite a few helpful flags in the past few weeks.  I still want this to be implemented, but maybe it could be different on SO, e.g. 1000 extra helpful flags like I said.